# Executable creation. Which path compatible Win10, Win7 and XP?

Tags: vb.net

Executable creation. Which path compatible Win10, Win7 and XP?

To create an executable file, this line of codes works on windows7 but does not work on XP =>
WriteAllBytes("C:\Program Files (x86)\File_Name.exe", My.Resources.File_Name)

On the other hand, the following line of codes runs on XP but does not work on Win7 =>
WriteAllBytes("C:\Program Files\File_Name.exe", My.Resources.File_Name)

What would be a compatible Win10, Win7 and XP SP3 path?

I tried the following environment variable, but it does not work =>
WriteAllBytes("%ProgramFiles%\File_Name.exe", My.Resources.File_Name)

Thank you for bringing me information on this subject.

```
WriteAllBytes("C:\Program Files(x86)\File_Name.exe", My.Resources.File_Name)

WriteAllBytes("C:\Program Files\File_Name.exe", My.Resources.File_Name)

WriteAllBytes("%ProgramFiles%\File_Name.exe", My.Resources.File_Name)
```

Depending on the different systems, the file is not created.

Comment: You need admin privileges to write to Program Files.  You should write to AppData.

Comment: This is not an admin problem, because in Visual app.manifest, I applied this control:
  <requestedExecutionLevel level = "requireAdministrator" uiAccess = "false" />
It's a path problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Environment.GetFolderPath` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) to find the actual path (which may not be in the `C:` drive).

Note that you will need admin privileges to write to it.